# Javascript debugger issue in VS2008

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, debugging, breakpoints

I'm having a really annoying problem with debugging javascript with VS2008.

If I simply press F5 (or choose 'start Debugging' from the Debug menu), the iexplore process is attached, but no breakpoints break in the scripts. The Script Documents tree doesn't even appear in the solution explorer.

I already know:

1. I can set a breakpoint in Javascript just fine. It does NOT show the "This point will not be hit" message.
2. Calling the debugger through using  the 'debugger' keyword works fine, but attaching to the iexplore process doesn't since it gives a "process already attached to a debugger" message.
3. Using the manual 'Attach to process...' works just fine. The Script Documents appears as well.
4. The project has recently been converted to a Web Application from a WebSite.

I already tried:

1. Clearing the IE cache.
2. Shutting down VS2008, Stopping the IIS and deleting the temporary asp.NET files restarting both IIS and VS2008 afterwards.
3. Setting IE7 as the default browser both for windows and for VS2008.
4. Resetting my user settings for VS2008.
5. Checking that IE script debugging is enabled.

Nothing has worked so far. While Attaching to process isn't too taxing, it is very annoying when I'm used to just hitting F5.

If anyone can think of a solution, please please please (I'm begging here!) let me know!

Comment: SirDemon, please don't add that tag back, I deleted it for a reason. The tag used for VS2008 is visualstudio2008. Please don't invent new tags if there are perfectly good tags already present.

Comment: The vs2008 tag was already there. I did not invent it. Plus, many of us search for vs2008 rather than visualstudio2008 which is longer.

Comment: I agree vs2008 would have been a better choice, but people went with the long one because there was already visualstudio2005 because there was already visualstudio because just "vs" was too short, and now we're stuck with it. If you spread answers along two tags they're harder to find,

Comment: so let's just stick with the most popular one - which, by far, is the long one, which has the added benefit of popping up when you look for both "visualstudio" and "2008", which means information will be easier to find...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is silverlight debugging enabled on the website project properties?  This will disable Javascript debugging.

Comment: damn! That was it! That is very good to know! Thanks a million!

Comment: Well, at least I can take comfort in only spending 3.5 hours on it until I asked the question here. Thanks again!